# Implement for in sql server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can i have a for loop

for example i have a table and want to do work for each record

Users:

```
Id      Name   Credit

1       A       0

2       B       0

3       C       0
```

want to write a query that fill credit from another table

```
update Users set credit=(select sum(credit) from creditLog where userId=...)
```

need create a for and send id of each user to this query

**Edit:**

according to answers write below query but when sum(price) from one table is NULL another table doesn't copy

```
UPDATE U SET    U.credit=Grp1.credit,U.show=Grp2.credit
FROM   users U 
INNER JOIN (SELECT userCode,ISNULL(Sum(price),0) credit FROM  userCredit  GROUP  BY userCode) GRP1 ON GRP1.userCode = U.code 
INNER JOIN (SELECT userCode,ISNULL(Sum(price),0) credit FROM  userPayment GROUP  BY userCode) GRP2 ON GRP2.userCode = U.code
```

Comment: You will need to join on to the user table then. e.g. INNER JOIN Users U on U.Id = creditLog.id

Comment: @Shnugo :  I edited the question

Comment: @SajjadZare, I edited my answer... The `INNER JOIN` should better be a `LEFT JOIN`, but still you'd need to handle the possible `NULL` value if there is no row at all...

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT: According to your edited question you might try this

```
UPDATE Users 
SET credit=(select isnull(sum(uc.price),0) 
            from userCredit AS uc 
            where uc.userCode=Users.code)
    ,show= (select isnull(sum(up.price),0) 
            from userPayment AS up 
            where up.userCode=Users.code);
```

#### previous

Avoid loops, they are the *naked evil* :-)

Google about "RBAR", "procedural" and "Set based"

Your statement should work without a loop anyway

```
update Users 
set credit=(select sum(cl.credit) 
            from creditLog AS cl 
            where cl.userId=Users.Id);
```

I added aliases to the tables names to avoid confusion...

Depending on your needs you might also use a `JOIN` or prepare a combined set as `CTE` and do the update there.

Comment: Thank you,it works but again has problem : some of users has payments but doesn't have credit or vice versa.then credit is 0,for example for user with id 20 , sum of price in table UserPayment is 50000,and sum of price in table UserPayment is NULL but credit of user after run this query is 0

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UPDATE U 
SET    U.credit = Grp.credit 
FROM   USER U 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT userid, 
                          Sum(credit) credit 
                   FROM   creditlog 
                   GROUP  BY userid) GRP 
               ON GRP.userid = U.userid
```

Comment: Thank you,it works.just if user don't have any record in creditLog return NULL,how can i check it that if null replace it with sth?

Comment: @SajjadZare Google for `ISNULL` function

Comment: @SajjadZare : Sorry, I did not get what exactly you are looking for.. Query to update only when sum(price)>0 or what?

Comment: Naveen, I think the problem is the inner join, which will return nothing, not even NULL, if there's nothing to return ...

Comment: Ok, then better to use LEFT JOIN